# Pandas Dataframe: Pairwise division of columns without replacement

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to divide all columns by each column but only once (A/B but not B/A)

From [Dividing each column by every other column and creating a new dataframe from the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103023/dividing-each-column-by-every-other-column-and-creating-a-new-dataframe-from-the)

and thanks to @COLDSPEED, the following code performs the division of all columns by every column (and adds the corresponding new columns).

I cannot figure out how to avoid the pair duplication.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,size=(5, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

ratio_df = pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference([col])].div(df[col], axis=0) \
                   for col in df.columns], axis=1)

print ratio_df
```

Which outputs:

Original dataframe

```
   A  B  C
0  6  3  7
1  4  6  2
2  6  7  4
3  3  7  7
4  2  5  4
```

Resulting dataframe

```
          B         C         A         C         A         B
0  0.500000  1.166667  2.000000  2.333333  0.857143  0.428571
1  1.500000  0.500000  0.666667  0.333333  2.000000  3.000000
2  1.166667  0.666667  0.857143  0.571429  1.500000  1.750000
3  2.333333  2.333333  0.428571  1.000000  0.428571  1.000000
4  2.500000  2.000000  0.400000  0.800000  0.500000  1.250000
```

In row 0, the value for the first column B is B/A or 3/6 = 0.5 and the first column A is A/B or 6/3 = 2

I would like to keep only one result for the pair operation (eg only left column / right column).

```
        A/B       A/C       B/C
0  2.000000  0.857143  0.428571
1  0.666667  2.000000  3.000000
2  0.857143  1.500000  1.750000
3  0.428571  0.428571  1.000000
4  0.400000  0.500000  1.250000
```

I was not able to find clues on this matter.

How could I resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
idx0,idx1 = np.triu_indices(df.shape[1],1)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,idx0].values/df.iloc[:,idx1])
c = df.columns.values
df_out.columns = c[idx0]+'/'+c[idx1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]: 
   A  B  C
0  6  3  7
1  4  6  2
2  6  7  4
3  3  7  7
4  2  5  4

In [59]: df_out
Out[59]: 
        A/B       A/C       B/C
0  2.000000  0.857143  0.428571
1  0.666667  2.000000  3.000000
2  0.857143  1.500000  1.750000
3  0.428571  0.428571  1.000000
4  0.400000  0.500000  1.250000
```

Alternative way to get `idx0` and `idx1` -

```
from itertools import combinations

idx0,idx1 = np.array(list(combinations(range(df.shape[1]),2))).T
```

Comment: For some reason my results are different row 0 A/B = 2, A/C = 0 and B/C = 0. Do you think it is a type issue (float)? Thanks

Comment: This worked df_out = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,idx0].values/df.iloc[:,idx1].astype(float))

Comment: @Diego It's because the inputs are all ints. Use : `from __future__ import division` at the top of the script and then use the proposed solution.